# How to select a word , word start with and including next word

Tags: javascript, regex

here is the strings:

```
stop
stop random some company
stopping non stop
arif
```

I am trying to match `stop, stop random, stopping` for this I try:

```
/stop|(stop.\w+)/
```

in this, both this part as `stop` and `(stop.\w+)` works separately. but not works combined. any idea?

---

Sample Code:

```js
const data = [
  "stop",
  "stop random some company",
  "stopping non stop",
  "arif"
]

const regex = /stop|(stop.\w+)/

data.forEach((word) => {
  const match = word.match(regex)
  if (match) {
    console.log(match[0])
  }
})
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Your pattern should be working.  Please include your code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you check here: https://regex101.com/r/8Md7LZ/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

- Start check with *stop*
- If there is a space, check till next word break
- If there is no space, check till next space
- Also check if the word is the last word.

```js
const data = [
  "stop",
  "stop random some company",
  "stopping non stop",
  "arif"
]

const regex = /stop([^ ]+| [^ ]+|$)/

data.forEach((word) => {
  const match = word.match(regex)
  if (match){
    console.log(match[0])
  }
})
```

Comment: This would also match non-target words like 'stopper', or 'stopped'

Comment: No issues, that's what I need. it should start with `stop`

Answer (score 2):

[ ]? - Match a space if present

[\w]* - matches any series of word characters

On [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FOGzn8/1).

```js
const data = [
  "stop",
  "stop random some company",
  "stopping non stop",
  "arif"
]

const regex = /stop[ ]?[\w]*/

data.forEach((word) => {
  const match = word.match(regex)
  if (match) {
    console.log(match[0])
  }
})
```